# form type mapped false symfony2

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have a trouble with a formtype with mapped=false.

In controller, I called the form with:

```
$form = $this->createForm(new JurisdictionUserNewType(), $jurisdiction_user);
```

This is my JurisdictionUserNewType:

```
class JurisdictionUserNewType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $transformer = new CapitalLetterToLowerCaseTransformer();

        $builder
            ->add('name', 'text')
            ->add($builder->create('email', 'email')
                           ->addModelTransformer($transformer))
            ->add('securityUser', new SecurityUserType(), array('mapped' => false))

            ->add('save', 'submit');

    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
           'data_class' => 'Radmas\Open010Bundle\Document\JurisdictionUser'
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'jurisdictionUserNew';
    }
}
```

This is my SecurityUserType :

```
class SecurityUserType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('first_name', null, ['label' => 'profile.edit.labels.first_name', 'icon_class' => 'fa fa-user'])
            ->add('last_name', null, ['label' => 'profile.edit.labels.last_name', 'icon_class' => 'fa fa-user'])
            ->add('nickname', null, ['label' => 'profile.edit.labels.nickname',
                'attr' => [ 'help_text' => 'profile.edit.labels.nickname_help'], 'icon_class' => 'fa fa-globe']);
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
           'data_class' => 'Radmas\SecurityBundle\Document\SecurityUser'
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'securityUser';
    }
}
```

When I put data in the form, I get the object jurisdictionUser in the modalview  but I dont get object securityUser.

Comment: Why do you have `array('mapped' => false)`?

Comment: because the document SecurityUser hasn´t any relations or references with the document JurisdictionUser.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you set `'mapped' => false` on any field, you're saying that that field isn't related to your entity, so you don't get it when you retrieve the entity from the submitted form.

You can get it anyway as a single field from the form, as:

```
$form->handleRequest($request); 
if ($form->isValid()) { 
    $entity = $form->getData(); 
    $securityUser = $form->get('securityUser')->getData();    
}
```

Comment: If I remove array('mapped' => false), I get this error: Neither the property "securityUser" nor one of the methods "getSecurityUser()", "isSecurityUser()", "hasSecurityUser()", "__get()" exist and have public access in class "Radmas\Open010Bundle\Document\JurisdictionUser"

Comment: Yeah, and that's up to you to decide if you want to map that or no. I just answered your question, how to get that data from the form.

Comment: For exmaple:                                                                                     $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid())
        {
            $data = $form->getData();                                                                                                         }