# Expected Argument, multiple file Upload Symfony?

Tags: sql, symfony, exception, doctrine

iam developing an multiple File Uploader.

To understand my problem, I try to describe it for you:

> I have two Entities (Objects and Images) with an "1 ... n" Relation, so that every Object can have "n" Images.

If I try to upload some Images, my Controller throw some exception, but I dont use Images Entity. Dont know how to fix this Problem and get some working Uploader.

> Expected argument of type "App\Entity\Images", "Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile" given.

Controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/new", name="objects_new", methods="GET|POST")
 */
public function new(Request $request): Response
{
    $object = new Objects();
    $form = $this->createForm(ObjectsType::class, $object);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $file = $form->get('logo')->getData();
        $fileName = $this->generateUniqueFileName().'.'.$file->guessExtension();
        $file->move(
            $this->getParameter('logo_directory'),
            $fileName
        );
        $object->setLogo($fileName);

        foreach ($request->files as $uploadedFile) {
            $uploadedFile = current($uploadedFile['file']);
            dump($uploadedFile);
        }
        $em->persist($object);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('home');
    }

    return $this->render('objects/new.html.twig', [
        'object' => $object,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ]);
}
```

Objects Entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Images", mappedBy="objects")
 */
private $images;
```

Images Entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Objects", inversedBy="images")
 */
private $objects;
```

ObjectsType:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('designation')
        ->add('description')
        ->add('place')
        ->add('coordL', null, array(
            'attr' => array('readonly' => 'true'),
        ))
        ->add('coordB', null, array(
            'attr' => array('readonly' => 'true'),
        ))
        ->add('category')
        ->add('logo', FileType::class, array('label' => ' ', 'data_class' => null))
        ->add('images', FileType::class, array('label' => 'Bilder (png, jpg, jpeg)', 'data_class' => null, 'multiple' => true))
    ;
}
```

If someone know, how to fix my Problem so help me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$images` field is set to be of `App\Entity\Images` type, but in your FormType, you're setting it to `FileType`.

Here is the line i'm talking about :

```
->add('images', FileType::class, array('label' => 'Bilder (png, jpg, jpeg)', 'data_class' => null, 'multiple' => true))
```

From this point, you have several ways to solve your problem, among which  :

- Either add the "mapped => false" option to that field in your FormType, then handle the process (of transforming a file to an `Image` entity ) manually from your controller.
- Or make a custom `ImageFormType`, mapped to your `Image` entity, which contains your FileType field ( could require some tricky code though )

See : 
[form type mapped false symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29793608/form-type-mapped-false-symfony2)
and 
https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/create_custom_field_type.html for more informations.

Comment: Thanks, i understand ;)