# How to set selected option in EntityType in Symfony 4

Tags: symfony4

How to set selected option in EntityType in form?

I've been following the documentation of Symfony 4

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('currencies', EntityType::class, [
        'mapped' => false,
        'class' => Currency::class,
        'choice_label' => 'code',
        'choice_value' => 'code',
        'label' => false,
        'data' => $options['current']
    ]);
}
```

I need to show form with pre-selected option in select element

Comment: This answer may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29793608/form-type-mapped-false-symfony2

Answer (score 0):

By setting the `mapped` option to `false` you are telling Symfony that it should ignore the field when reading or writing.

See: https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#mapped.

Setting it to `true` (or omitting it as `true` is the default) should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

even though this question is old, but for the sake of those who may end up here.

if your form is not mapped to a `data_class`, pass an object of your EntityType through options to the `data` option as shown below:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('currencies', EntityType::class, [
        'mapped' => false,
        'class' => Currency::class,
        'choice_label' => 'code',
        'choice_value' => 'code',
        'label' => false,
        'data' => $options['current'] // instance of Currency
    ]);
}
```